# Ubuntu 10.04 on Dell XPS 1702x: wlan0 No such device

Tags: 10.04, intel-wireless

I am using a Dell XPS L702x and I am using Ubuntu 10.04 because I need to use f77 (don't ask) and I wasn't able to get it working on later versions of ubuntu.

I cannot use the wifi at all. I have tried to fix it and have had limited success (changed the output from rfkill list all from Hard blocked: yes, to hard blocked: no).

Here is the output from rfkill list all

```
aodhan@aodhan-laptop:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Here is the output from iwconfig:

```
aodhan@aodhan-laptop:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

pan0      no wireless extensions.
```

And here is the output from ifconfig -a:

```
aodhan@aodhan-laptop:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:f9:dd:3d:f2:f7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.17  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5ef9:ddff:fe3d:f2f7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2894 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3317567 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:505049 (505.0 KB)
          Interrupt:30 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:720 (720.0 B)  TX bytes:720 (720.0 B)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7e:7e:e8:39:70:af  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And finally, the output from lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0104 (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0116 (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1c4b (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1246 (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 008a (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation Device 0194 (rev 04)
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Please help me!

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

Further info - this is a dual install with a windows 7 system as the other option. However, I can't access that until tomorrow (I won't have access to the windows 7 disc until then, and grub isn't letting me load it). Therefore, I can't be sure whether it still works on that or not. It used to, though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution to your problem is to update your kernel to 2.6.38

Quote from the **theunsheydenrych** from [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1707814&page=3) forum post about the problem

> I can confirm that the wifi is working after i installed the 2.6.38
>   kernel.
>
> I have a Dell XPS 17 702x , with Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)
>
> You helped a lot in sorting this issue out, thanks

to do this you will need to add a [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) and update the kernel from it

open a terminal and enter this command

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa`

then update..

`sudo apt-get update`

finally install the kernel and headers..

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.38-1-generic linux-image-2.6.38-1-generic`

hopefully this will get your wi-fi up and running